# Block sending sms in android

Tags: android

Hi i've found many related threads , but no one has given answer ... can any one help me out in finding the way to **block the outgoing sms**

Comment: well am able to block incoming sms but not the outgoing sms

Comment: Search around. [Here's another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547459/block-outgoing-sms-by-contentobserver).

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, this is not supported.

Comment: no other means for this ... beacuse its main criteria in my project, how about the implementation in apps like textecution