# Need to detect SMS Sent in android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-sms

I know this question is way old and may be duplicate, but I have a particular query based on it for which I am still trying to find the solution.

As far as I know, `ContentObserver` on URI `content://sms` will be triggered when ever there is change in data.
I have tried,

https://katharnavas.wordpress.com/2012/01/18/listening-for-outgoing-sms-or-send-sms-in-android/

[Android : Catching Outgoing SMS using ContentObserver or receiver not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34692384/android-catching-outgoing-sms-using-contentobserver-or-receiver-not-working)

and many more...

As per my understanding this can only be achieved by Content provider and there is no  broadcast to handle this. Also `content://sms/sent` doesn't work at

```
contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), true, observer);
```

Am receiving the `onChange` for each messaging data whether its SMS sent, received, deleted. So as per the documentation of android and other stackoverflow links I found using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns.html#MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT as comparison method.

So my check goes as,

```
@Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms");
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        String protocol = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("protocol"));
        Log.d(TAG, "protocol = " + protocol);
        int type = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("type"));
        Log.d(TAG, "onChange: type = " + type);
        // I have even tried with protocol == null check.
        if (type == 2 && smsChecker(id)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Sent sms");
        }
        cur.close();
    }

    private boolean smsChecker(String smsId) {
        boolean flagSMS = true;

        if (smsId.equals(lastSmsId)) {
            flagSMS = false;
        }
        else {
            lastSmsId = smsId;
        }

        return flagSMS;
    }
```

So my question here is, If I delete any messages or trigger a outgoing message I receive type 2 on my HTC phone - L OS (sometimes for incoming message too I see type==2).

How can I separate this onChange request, as I am particularly looking for SMS SENT change.